# Why isn't the component child rendered?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I have written the following code in **APP.js** component:

```
import React from "react";
import Exam from "./exam.js";

export default function App() {
   return (
      <Exam>
        <h1>hashemi</h1>
      </Exam>
   );
}
```

And I have written the following code in **exam.js** component:

```
import React from "react";

const Exam = ({child}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>parastoo</p>
      {child}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Exam;
```

But the output shows this:

> parastoo

What is the problem? Why doesn't the child `<h1>` render?

Answer (score 1):

Child components are passes via the **`children`** prop to the component, even if there is only a single child:

```
const Exam = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>parastoo</p>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called `props.children`. Read from the documentation section [Containment](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment).

```
const Exam = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>parastoo</p>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In React, you can pass props, or properties, to child components. Say you have an App component which renders a child component called CurrentDate which is a stateless functional component. You can pass CurrentDate a date property by writing:

```
const CurrentDate = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      { /* change code below this line */ }
      <p>The current date is: {props.date} </p>
      { /* change code above this line */ }
    </div>
  );
};
```

Calender is a parent Component, you can pass Calender a date property by writing

```
class Calendar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>What date is it?</h3>
        { /* change code below this line */ }
        <CurrentDate date={Date()}/>
        { /* change code above this line */ }
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```